# XD/NX Bit in UNIX [Memory Security]

Tags: memory

I have been reading about XD/NX bit used in Memory Pages for security. I understand it is a security feature that can help reduce system exposure to viruses and malicious code. If enabled, processor prevents the execution of code in data-only memory pages.

However, I want to now understand:

- What does it not help to protect against?
- When should it be used?

Any answers/hints would be appreciated!

Comment: If you understand what the NX flag protects against, then it should be pretty obvious what it does not protect against. The list of sports that are not golf is quite long and not a very useful one.

Answer (score 1):

NX (also called DEP, Data Execution Protection, on Windows) only protects against exploits that attempt to drop executable machine code - typically called a "shellcode" - into data memory (typically stack or heap) and then run it. This is the easiest way to get from a buffer overflow (one of the most common forms of memory corruption) to arbitrary code execution, so it's a big deal to block that, but it doesn't directly protect against anything else..

NX does also help somewhat with dynamic security testing. Generally speaking, such testing desires that the program being tested crash immediately upon unexpected behavior occurring, because that's the easiest thing to monitor for and you want the monitor to trip as close to the source of the problem as possible. So, for example, suppose you're using the technique called "fuzzing", where malformed data is generated procedurally (often by randomly mutating valid data) and fed to a program / API. The malformed data causes the instruction pointer - the register in the CPU that indicates where to read the next instruction of machine code from - to jump to an incorrect address. If the address is valid (mapped into the process' address space) and executable, then the CPU might spend a while doing random nonsense operations before attempting anything that actually causes a crash, which may make it harder for the tester to figure out where the bug is and how bad it is. If the address is valid but is non-executable memory, then the process will crash immediately with an NX violation exception. That's extremely useful information for the tester; not only does the crash happen very close to the point where execution reaches the bug, it also clearly indicates the problem (instruction pointer influenced by bad data) in a way that makes it easy to triage the vulnerability (guaranteed at least denial-of-service, almost certainly usable for arbitrary code execution except maybe if the IP want to NULL).

As others have pointed out, the list of things that NX doesn't protect against is too large to enumerate. However, as general categories, it includes the following:

- Attacks where the instruction pointer is aimed at executable code but in a way that the developer didn't intend (return-to-libc, return-oriented programming, etc.)
- Attacks where the goal is merely to cause a crash (denial-of-service)
- Attacks with memory corruption but where the goal doesn't involve changing the instruction sequence at all (buffer overreads such as Heartbleed, data leaks that expose ASLR masks, overwrites that bypass security checks in normal execution, etc.)
- Attacks that don't require memory corruption at all (program logic errors of basically all sorts, from failure to check an ACL to TOCTOU to `goto fail;` to filename path traversal to... you hopefully get the idea)

---

There's approximately no reason to ever *not* use NX these days. Some very old software might be incompatible if it tries things like compiling a script to machine code, writing it to data memory, and then trying to execute it; you can still do this (web browsers do it all the time for JavaScript) but you have to use a system call to change the memory protection (remove NX and add RO) before execution, and sufficiently old software won't know to do so. However, NX has been around in both software and hardware support for over two decades, some operating systems now force it on by default for all software or at least all software that doesn't get a specific exception, and all modern compilers (well, properly *linkers*) should by default flag binaries as supporting it.

However, as alluded to above, NX is far from a complete protection, even against "memory corruption leads to control of the instruction pointer" vulnerabilities. For that, you need additional mitigations such as ASLR, which should *also* be used on all modern software.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't protect you from ROP chains, i.e, code that already exists in the target application itself. It also doesn't protect you from memory leak type vulnerabilities. In-fact, on its own it doesn't protect you from a whole lot because you can simply use the aforementioned ROP to turn NX off on the page in question.

Secondly, it should always be used along with other mitigations such as ASLR, etc.

*As pointed out in the comments, this question is too open for an elaborate answer to be provided*.